# SQL Insert Ordered List With Increasing Timestamp

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In an application I am working on, I am storing "Notes" which basically contain some arbitrary (user-defined) text and the time it was created. The time is very important and these Notes need to be accurately ordered when sorted by time. Right now the time is assigned by the SQL database itself when the Note is Inserted, and it works well for inserting one Note at a time.

However, new requirements have led to the ability to create multiple notes and submit them in a single request. When these notes are later retrieved from the database, ordering them by time should result in the original ordering provided in the request. My worries are that inserting the list normally would either not guarantee the order of individual elements, or would not guarantee distinct times at all.

There is a simple solution, which is to simply Insert each note in order using separate transactions. From my understanding of SQL this would have a significant impact on performance relative to making a single transaction, so I would like to avoid that if an alternative is reasonable.

For a little more background information, the application is written in C# and uses Entity Framework to communicate with a database defined Code First. The Notes are created in an ASP.NET MVC client and then sent to an ASP.NET Web API server which handles the database access. As far as I'm aware, none of it uses .NET Core.

Comment: Might be a silly answer, but can't you send both the notes and the time they created in the application to the database to be inserted into the table?

Comment: When you say timestamp I assume you mean a datetime datatype that has that name? timestamp is a datatype in sql server that has nothing to do with time or dates.

Comment: One could ask that if two notes are inserted at the same time how would you know which note was created first?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze The way we have our UI set up, in order to include the original time that information would have to be stored in HTML at some point. There's likely a way to work around it, but we prefer having the database be the authority of "when things happened" anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the comment, I will edit the post to clarify that I mean "a datetime column" rather than a "timestamp column"

Comment: Why don't you have an Identity column on the table as well as the datetime column and insert the Notes in the order they were created by the application and then retrieve them in Identity column order

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze the results are explicitly sorted by the creation time later in the process.

Comment: So explicitly sort them by the identity later in the process instead.

Comment: Or supply your own DateTime value instead of letting the trigger (or other DB side action) define it for the entity. Or add a sort column. There are many easy ways to do this. And I have to also agree that the easiest one to use is the use of an Identity column.

Answer (score 1):

The Notes entity just needs a NoteId Identity column.  SQL Server guarantees that identity values are assigned in the order of rows, even when inserting multiple rows in a single statement.  You then can order the Notes by NoteId to retrieve them by insertion order.

Comment: The notes must be in the correct order when explicitly sorted by their creation time. I will update the question to clarify this.

Comment: That's a strange requirement.  To do that you would need to put a unique index on creation time and ensure that you don't install multiple rows at the same time.  You can use datetime2(7) to have enough time precision to make this work, but you will need to manually assign incremental time values when inserting multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the timestamps are created by the database, do you mean that column has a default value of SYSDATETIME()? If so you can override that by setting the date property in your code when a note is created. That way you can preserve the chronological order while saving in a single transaction.

Comment: We are using the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` defined in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. From my experience, any information in a property with that attribution is ignored when inserting, but I will try and see if I am mistaken.